# Is there a term for a question and answer pair?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that encapsulates the idea of a question and answer pairing or grouping? So far, google has turned up nothing helpful on the topic. Naturally, reviewing the options for both questions and answers in a thesaurus turns up nothing because the alternatives are similar to the idea of one or the other, but not both combined.

Comment: Context is everything. ''Resistance is futile". [to that idea]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd call it a...

> [question and answer **interchange**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22question%20and%20answer%20interchange%22&oq=%22question%20and%20answer%20interchange%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.953j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) *(21,300 hits on Google)*

Or just plain...

[**interchange**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interchange) *- mutual interaction; the activity of reciprocating or exchanging (esp. information)*

Answer (score 6):

Supplementing FF's answer:

Or just:

> Question and answer
>   Q & A

Answer (score 2):

This might be esoteric and on the edge, but we don't really know the context for OP's query:

What came to mind was a "challenge".  When you can't remember your password on your banking site, as an example, they will give you a "challenge", a "challenge question", or a "security question" (I've heard all three).  They would seem different from a regular question in that there is supposed to be only one acceptable answer paired to the question portion of the challenge.  A soldier on guard duty might also issue a challenge that would need to be returned with the correct paired answer.

Just an idea.  "Challenge" was single word as requested.  Like I say, we don't have a lot of information.

Comment: This one did it for me, thanks. And as mentioned elsewhere on the page, I did need a variable name! :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a request for a computer program variable name.

In that domain, related pairs of things are often referred to as "[tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)"s or "[pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths)"s. So if it were me, I'd name that variable `question_answer_pair`, or perhaps `qa_pair` for short.

Comment: If it is "a request for a computer program variable name", it's off-topic.

Comment: @TrevorD ...which is I suspect the reason the OQ avoided the issue of what he wanted it for in the text of his question.

Comment: -1 Regardless of *why* OP asked the question, suggesting program variable names isn't what ELU answers are for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *Requesting* program variable names perhaps isn't what ELU questions are for. However, I always endevor in answers to help the requestor with the root of their problem. If the question itself is out of bounds, that should be modded on the question, not my answer.

Comment: ...not that my answer can't be crappy all on its own. :-)

Comment: @ T.E.D.: Well, *if* you're right about how OP intends to use any suggestions, yours seems a perfectly good "answer" to me. But in that case the question must surely be Off Topic. Thus far I have no opinion on OP's possible motivation, but I do agree that it's only common courtesy to resolve his problem if it's easily addressed. Having said that, if the nature of an answer presupposes that the question itself is OT, I think that answer should be posted as a ***comment*** (and probably accompanied by a closevote).